How to use spring-data-opensearch-starter
I want to make use of https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch to in my spring boot based app.
I tried to follow the instructions there to import and configure the client but with no success:
Below is my code:
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-opensearch-starter.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensearch-java</artifactId>
    <version>${opensearch-java.version}</version>
</dependency>

OpenSearchCustomClientConfig.java
import org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.opensearch.data.client.orhlc.AbstractOpenSearchConfiguration;
import org.opensearch.data.client.orhlc.ClientConfiguration;
import org.opensearch.data.client.orhlc.RestClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OpenSearchCustomClientConfig extends AbstractOpenSearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient opensearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:32526")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}

MyApp.java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    }
}

MyService.java
@Autowired
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

...

final var queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", "120");

final var searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.size(1000);
searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);

var sr = new SearchRequest();
sr.indices("pdf-search");
sr.source(searchSourceBuilder);
var response = restHighLevelClient.search(sr, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

1 try:
OpenSearchCustomClientConfig.java doesn't compile because of the error "Cannot resolve RestHighLevelClient"
2 try:
Remove
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>

from pom.xml
error:
"The bean 'opensearchClient', defined in class path resource [org/opensearch/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OpenSearchClientConfigurations$OpenSearchClientConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [myapp/configuration/OpenSearchCustomClientConfig.class] and overriding is disabled."

3 try:
Add
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

to application.yml
error: "Parameter 4 of constructor in MyService required a bean of type 'org.opensearch.client.RestHighLevelClient' that could not be found."
4 try:
Removed code from 3 try and use this instead:
spring:
  main
    autoconfigure:
      exclude: org.opensearch.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OpenSearchClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration

error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchOperations' defined in class path resource [OpenSearchCustomClientConfig.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:577) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.opensearch.data.client.orhlc.OpenSearchRestTemplate] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

I'm out of ideas what should be done to configure it...
Using
spring-boot 3.2.4


See "2 try" section in the question - I returned it. But according to their tutorial they suggest to act in this way :)

Within your option 4 add another class to avoid ElasticSearch auto configuration from starting.  Add the following class to your exclude list:
ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class


No such class in my class path

What version of spring boot are you using?  Might be helpful to see what versions of opensearch libraries you are using as well.

I've added it to the question - 3.2.4

I assume that you use Spring Data Elasticsearch with version above 4.0, some deprecated API already removed which will cause this error.
you can find more details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/

I've solved in this way.
Maven (Opensearch official doc):
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <!-- https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch/issues/121 -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensearch-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.0</version>
</dependency>

Then on Java code:
@Bean
public OpenSearchTemplate getOpenSearchTemplate() {

    log.debug("Connecting to OpenSearch '{}'...", endpoint);

    SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
            .withDefaultTrustMaterial()
            .withUnsafeHostnameVerifier() // <-- !!!
            .build();

    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(endpoint)
            .usingSsl(sslFactory.getSslContext(), sslFactory.getHostnameVerifier())
            .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
            .withBasicAuth(username, password)
            .build();

    OpenSearchClient client = OpenSearchClients.createImperative(clientConfiguration);

    return new OpenSearchTemplate(client);
}

Then you can use the ElasticsearchOperations to run your queries.
